# Initiating a perl script from within X11 environment/terminal window

Tags: linux, perl, admin, x11

I have a perl script that I want to run periodically from a cron job. The Perl script uses the WWW::Mechanize::Firefox module and X11::GUITest module.

When I run the script from a remote terminal window, I get this error:

`X11::GUITest - This program is designed to run in X Windows!
INIT failed--call queue aborted.`

I'm guessing I'm going to run into the same problem when the script is run by the cron job. How can I start the script so it is running in an X11 environment?

Comment: Isn't it as a simple as setting the `DISPLAY` env var to a suitable value?

Comment: I agree w/ ikegami, but would also like to add that you need to make sure X11 is running, or including a way to start it in your Perl script.  The cron could run when no one is logged in, and I'm not sure that X11 can even run "headless" like that.

Comment: Thanks. X11 will be running on the machine at all times. Can you please give more details on where/how to set the `DISPLAY` variable?

Comment: You need to wrap this in a shell script and set DISPLAY in that script. A suitable value is usually ":0.0". You probably want to run the script as the user who owns the X11 session.

Comment: OK, adding `$ENV{'DISPLAY'} = ':0.0';` into the top of my module that used `X11::GUITest` did the trick.

Thanks!